# Extracting 'hour' from 'time_stamp' with QGIS

Tags: qgis, expression, time, string, qgis-expression

I am trying to extract the hour from my time_stamp which is in the format `dd/mm/yyyy 00:00:00` as a textstring.

I am using the expression `hour("time_stamp")` in the field calculator, but the expression isn't working. I have tried converting the time_stamp into different formats but none of them seem to work!

Comment: Which software are you using, and is the time_stamp field of type DateTime or String (text)?

Comment: The software is QGIS and the time_stamp field is string

Comment: It was - I typed it into the question incorrectly

Comment: instead of converting to a datetime, you could also use various text extraction functions to grab those two digits. This is assuming that every time_stamp is formatted the same way, of course.

Comment: @lambertj if every time_stamp isn't formatted the same way the conversion to datetime will also fail (but it's probably better to get an error rather than extracting the wrong part)

Comment: [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 7):

If your field is a string you should convert to datetime before using the hour function. To convert to datetime you need to provide the format in which your string encodes the datetime, so your expression becomes:

```
 hour(to_datetime("time_stamp", 'dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss'))
```

Answer (score 3):

A solution using Regular Expressions ([see e.g. here for Regular Expression basics](https://regexone.com/)):

```
regexp_matches( 
    "TimeStamp",
    '(\\d{4} )(\\d{2})'
)[1]
```

**Explanation**

- [`regexp_matches()`](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/expressions/functions_list.html#regexp-matches) to get an array of (here: two) capturing groups as follows.
- Each capturing group is in brackets: `()`
- `(\\d{4} )` (including a space after `}`) looks for a first capturing group consisting of 4 digits, followed by a space (the year). In QGIS, backslash characters must be double escaped (masked), so here you have double backslahses `\\` for the ["any digit" character `\d`](https://regexone.com/lesson/letters_and_digits).
- `(\\d{2})` looks for a second capturing group consisting of two digits (hour) and that follows immediately after the first one.
- [`[1]`](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/expressions/functions_list.html#expression-function-operators-index) index operator to get the second element (index starts with 0 for first element)

**Variant**

Look for the first appearence of two digitis before a colon:

```
regexp_matches( 
    "TimeStamp",
    '(\\d{2}):'
)[0]
```

Answer (score 1):

In R, you can use

```
hour(as.PosixCT("TimeStamp", format = "%dd/%mm/%yyyy %h:%m:%s"))
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are sure the string always will be the same format, a quick and dirty way to get the hour would be

```
string_to_array(string_to_array("<fieldname>",' ')[1],':')[0]
```

i.e; split the timestamp on space, use the second part, split that part by colon and use the first part from that. If you want the hour as a number, wrap that in to_int(), i.e

```
to_int(string_to_array(string_to_array("<fieldname>",' ')[1],':')[0])
```